# Objective C ViewController rotating to Landscape unexpectedly

Tags: ios, objective-c, orientation, uiinterfaceorientation, portrait

I'm having some issues with a view that I want to only allow a portrait view. Here is my code:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

-(UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

This works great until another view is presented over this one. When the next view controller is dismissed, the first view controller seems to ignore shouldAutorotate and it goes to landscape and portrait unexpectedly. How can I solve this problem?

Edit: Please note that I am using other view controllers that do use landscape.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the latest version of XCode. Simply go to Project Target -> Deployment Info 
-> Device Orientation and simply check portrait and uncheck the rest :)

Comment: It looks like this will work. I would like to add though, that it seems I will have to make another storyboard for views that I only want to display portrait orientations since I have other view controllers that do use landscape.

Comment: Ok, I was wrong. This will not work. It only lets you set the device orientations this way for the entire project, not individual storyboards. This will not work if you need to use landscape for some views.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is a bit hacky, but it works. If anyone else has anything better please let me know.

First I selected my project and selected the target, then I went into General -> Deployment Info like @Bejibun suggested. I unchecked everything but Portrait.

Then I added the following code:

AppDelegate.h:

```
#import "ViewControllerClass.h"
```

AppDelegate.m:

```
-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    if ([[[[window.rootViewController presentedViewController] presentedViewController] presentedViewController] isKindOfClass:[ViewControllerClass class]] && ![[[[window.rootViewController presentedViewController] presentedViewController] presentedViewController] presentedViewController])
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}
```

This

> [[[[window.rootViewController presentedViewController]
>   presentedViewController] presentedViewController]
>   isKindOfClass:[ViewControllerClass class]]

tells me if the root view controller's next view controller's next view controller is of the class type that I want to only have portrait view. This is how it should always be presented, but this is where I would like to have some method that returns the bottom most view controller so I don't have to do [[presentedViewController] presentedViewController] etc...

This

> ![[[[window.rootViewController presentedViewController]
>   presentedViewController] presentedViewController]
>   presentedViewController]

allows me to make sure there is not another view controller over this one since I may have more view controllers on top of each other in this app.

Answer (score 0):

1. It's better to use UINavigationController for navigation between viewcontrollers then presenting them.
2. To force presentation of viewcontrollers in different orientations, you should subclass UINavigationController and add code to it's subclass (will force navigation controller to use orientation of top viewcontroller):

   ```
   -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
   {
       return [[self topViewController] shouldAutorotate];
   }

   -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
   {
       return [[self topViewController] supportedInterfaceOrientations];
   }

   -(UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
   {
       return [[self topViewController] preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Before top landscape view controller dismissed, send a notification to AppDelegate, set a variable allowViewToRotate = NO, and

```
-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0)
{
if(self.allowViewToRotate)
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
else
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
}
```

This works for me, after the top landscape viewcontroller dismissed, the next controller on screen still keep portrait.